# Increase sga_max_size on Oracle 10g Windows

Tags: oracle, windows, oracle-10g

i would like to increase the max memory size of one Oracle 10g database installed on Windows.

The v$parameter shows

> sga_max_size 452984832

and

> sga_target 452984832

Note that the ISDEFAULT column for sga_max_size is TRUE and every other IS settings are FLASE

I have found a init.ora file in the admin\MYINSTANCE\scripts and i have changed both parameters and restarted the service with no success.

There is another init.ora file in srvm\admin folder but i don't know if i can modify this one.

Where should i modify this parameter to have the memory increased ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Oracle no longer uses the `init.ora` file anymore. It uses the `spfileSID.ora` in the `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs` directory. This is a binary file. Tio change the parameter(s) you should use:

```
alter system set sga_max_size=XXXM scope=spfile;
```

Now restart the database and the `SGA_MAX_SIZE` should be set at `XXXM`. Now you can alter the `SGA_TARGET`:

```
alter system set sga_target=XXXM scope=both;
```